# Give access to all (virtual) products with one subscription

Tags: magento-1.8, product, user-roles

I'm just discover Magento and I asked a question. 
I'm looking for a way to give access to all products of the store with a subscription.

Products are files. I would when a client buy a subscription, he can download files attached but for all the products of the store. 
The goal is client doesn't make an order each time he would download files.

Answer (score 1):

I do think the best way is to use bundled Product.

Create Virtual Products in magento, and then make a Bundled Product of all those you want to offer.

Client can subscribe to this bundled product and get all the downloads. 
Refer : http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product

Comment: Hi echoashu,

Thank you for your answer. But I understanded that bundled product is "one product" with "sub products" or "options".

In my case, I'm looking for a way where user paid one time and can download each separate product of the store.

So I think, we can not do that with bundled product.

Regards

Comment: I actually am working on a project with the same requirement and I've already come up with the same approach.